# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined Angular 9

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-upgrade

[image]

I am doing some R&D of upgrading from Angular 8 to Angular 9 my application stopped working suddenly. Home page also not displaying.
I received many warnings and error message of type undefined. Then I did 3 changes in my tsconfig.jston file by adding as shown below. However, application home page displaying blank. and in the console receiving vendor.js errors with warnings. Someone please help me with this, Thanks!

```
"noUnusedLocals": false,
"noUnusedParameters":false,
"skipLibCheck": true,
```

Comment: You have an error in your javascript. some variable is undefined. somewhere you are doing `undefined.type` or `undefined.type()`.

Comment: Thanks @Giannis, however how do I find which .ts file exactly this causing an issue. because vendor.js is completely different file. I want to identify from which .ts file its propagating, any idea plz.

Comment: It could be probably caused by a third-party package you have installed as vendor.js includes them. Maybe a package you already use is not compatible with Angular 9.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn  I tried to look for solution however no luck. Vendor.js is Angular's file. I did upgrade from Angular8 to Angular9. And then this problem got started. Do you know something about Ivy.

Comment: As @Giannis mentioned it could be a package that isn't compatible with Angular 9. Check your dependencies and make sure that they are compatible with Angular 9.

Comment: Thanks both of you, the problem was with Angular 9 IVY

Comment: This URL saved a day, many thanks everyone.https://levelup.gitconnected.com/upgrade-to-angular-9-within-10-minutes-671c6fd6174b

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, @Giannis and @GetOffMyLawn.....there was a problem with Angular 9 IVY...
by following settings mentioned in this url for tsconfig, package.json saved a day. Many thanks!

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/upgrade-to-angular-9-within-10-minutes-671c6fd6174b